# Chemscheme in float environment for implementation in tabular

Tags: floats, tabularx

In my dissertation, I am using Chemscheme for the consistent numbering of molecules. I would like to include some of the schemes I create in the headers of reaction tables. I know that I can do so with regular graphics using e.g. minipages. 
The schemes are apparently incompatible with the float environment though. Probably, there is an easy fix that someone who encountered this problem before came up with. I'd be very happy to hear it.
Please let me know, if I did not explain properly! This is my first question in a forum. 
Here is a picture of what it is supposed to look like.
[image]

And here is what I hope you meant by MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, headsepline, DIV10, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}                   
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
    \schemeref[TMP1]{benzonitril}
    \schemeref[TMP2]{benzylamin}
    \includegraphics{90-Nitrilhydrierung/Abbildungen/01_benzonitril}
\end{scheme}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Title.}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        \hline
        Catalyst & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TON} \\
        \ & Compound & Compound & Compound \\
        \hline
        1 & 8 & 39 & 0\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you start with a MWE (minimal working example) in your question. This is much easier to start working on an answer. Feel free to add a picture of what you want to obtain.

Comment: In the title and the text you refer to the [`chemscheme`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemscheme) package but the tag you used says [`chemschemex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemschemex). Which one do you actually use?  Apart from that, would using [`chemnum`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) be an option for you?

Comment: @ArneTimperman, thank you for your answer. I added a picture of a table similar to the one I would like to obtain. Also, I tried to give a suitable MWE. Let me know, if I should add more or different information.

Comment: @leandriis, I didn't realize I tagged Chemschemex. I could not add Chemscheme though, so I deleted the tag. Concerning the use of chemnum: This package is only convenient for moderately complex chemical structures, but not for the ones I am working with (most of them are large complexes with sterical implications and I would much prefer to use Chemdraw for their implementation).

Comment: @MeriaMaus: `chemnum` works perfectly fine with chemdraw files. If you add a textbox with `TMP1` to a chemdraw file, save it as .eps and include it into your document via `\includegraphics`, you can use the `\replacecmpd` command to replace the `TMP1` tag in the inserted image by an automatically created number.

Comment: @leandriis: Would I be able to use the chemnum-images in the tables as mentioned above? What are the differences/the key advantages of using chemnum compared to Chemscheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a MWE showing how to use an image where the compound numbers are created with the help of the `chemscheme` package inside of a `tabular` enviornment:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, headsepline, DIV10, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}                   
\usepackage{chemstyle}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Title.}
    \schemeref[TMP1]{benzonitril}
    \schemeref[TMP2]{benzylamin}
    \includegraphics{<image-name>}\\ 
    \vspace*{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        \hline
        Catalyst & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TON} \\
        \ & Compound & Compound & Compound \\
        \hline
        1 & 8 & 39 & 0\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Here is a variant using `chemnum` instead of `chemscheme`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, headsepline, DIV10, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}                   
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Title.}
    \replacecmpd{benzonitril}
    \replacecmpd{benzylamin}
    \includegraphics{<image-name>}\\ 
    \vspace*{10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        \hline
        Catalyst & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TON} \\
        \ & Compound & Compound & Compound \\
        \hline
        1 & 8 & 39 & 0\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware that I just needed to ommit the "\begin{scheme} \end{scheme}" within the table environment, which makes perfect sense now that I know! It works perfectly now! I'll try to use chemnum on some examples and compare the practicability. Thanks a lot, @leandriis!